# label-encoder encoding a dataframe without encoding NaN missing values

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains Numerical, categorical and NaN values.

```
    customer_class  B   C
0   OM1            1    2.0
1   NaN        6    1.0
2   OM1            9    NaN
....
```

I need a LabelEncoder that keeps my missing values as 'NaN' to use an Imputer afterwards.

So I have would like to use this code in order to encode my dataframe by keeping NaN value .

here is the code :

```
   class LabelEncoderByCol(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,col):
        #List of column names in the DataFrame that should be encoded
        self.col = col
        #Dictionary storing a LabelEncoder for each column
        self.le_dic = {}
        for el in self.col:
            self.le_dic[el] = LabelEncoder()

    def fit(self,x,y=None):
        #Fill missing values with the string 'NaN'
        x[self.col] = x[self.col].fillna('NaN')
        for el in self.col:
            #Only use the values that are not 'NaN' to fit the Encoder
            a = x[el][x[el]!='NaN']
            self.le_dic[el].fit(a)
        return self

    def transform(self,x,y=None):
        #Fill missing values with the string 'NaN'
        x[self.col] = x[self.col].fillna('NaN')
        for el in self.col:
            #Only use the values that are not 'NaN' to fit the Encoder
            a = x[el][x[el]!='NaN']
            #Store an ndarray of the current column
            b = x[el].get_values()
            #Replace the elements in the ndarray that are not 'NaN'
            #using the transformer
            b[b!='NaN'] = self.le_dic[el].transform(a)
            #Overwrite the column in the DataFrame
            x[el]=b
        #return the transformed D


col = data1['customer_class']
LabelEncoderByCol(col)
LabelEncoderByCol.fit(x=col,y=None)
```

But I got this error : 
    846         if mask.any():
--> 847             raise ValueError('%s not contained in the index' % str(key[mask]))
    848         self._set_values(indexer, value)
    849

ValueError: ['OM1' 'OM1' 'OM1' ... 'other' 'EU' 'EUB'] not contained in the index

Any idea please to resolve this error?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things jumped out to me when I tried to reproduce:

1. Your code seems to expect a dataframe will be passed to your class. But in your example you passed a series. I fixed this by wrapping the series as a dataframe before passing it to your class: `col = pd.DataFrame(data1['customer_class'])`.
2. In your class' `__init__` method it seemed like you had intended to iterate through a list of column names, but instead were actually iterating through all of your columns, series by series. I fixed this by changing the appropriate line to: `self.col = col.columns.values`.

Below, I've pasted in my modifications to your class' `__init__` and `fit` methods (my only modification to the `transform` method was to have it return the modified dataframe):

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_class': ['OM1', np.nan, 'OM1'],
                      'B': [1,6,9],
                      'C': [2.0, 1.0, np.nan]})

class LabelEncoderByCol(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,col):
        #List of column names in the DataFrame that should be encoded
        self.col = col.columns.values
        #Dictionary storing a LabelEncoder for each column
        self.le_dic = {}
        for el in self.col:
            self.le_dic[el] = LabelEncoder()

    def fit(self,x,y=None):
        #Fill missing values with the string 'NaN'
        x = x.fillna('NaN')
        for el in self.col:
            #Only use the values that are not 'NaN' to fit the Encoder
            a = x[el][x[el]!='NaN']
            self.le_dic[el].fit(a)
        return self

    def transform(self,x,y=None):
        #Fill missing values with the string 'NaN'
        x[self.col] = x[self.col].fillna('NaN')
        for el in self.col:
            #Only use the values that are not 'NaN' to fit the Encoder
            a = x[el][x[el]!='NaN']
            #Store an ndarray of the current column
            b = x[el].get_values()
            #Replace the elements in the ndarray that are not 'NaN'
            #using the transformer
            b[b!='NaN'] = self.le_dic[el].transform(a)
            #Overwrite the column in the DataFrame
            x[el]=b
        return x
```

I am able to run the following lines (also slightly modified from your initial implementation) with no error:

```
col = pd.DataFrame(data1['customer_class'])
lenc = LabelEncoderByCol(col)
lenc.fit(x=col,y=None)
```

I can then access the classes for the `customer_class` column from your example:

```
lenc.fit(x=col,y=None).le_dic['customer_class'].classes_
```

Which outputs:

```
array(['OM1'], dtype=object)
```

Finally, I can transform the column using your class' `transform` method:

```
lenc.transform(x=col,y=None)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
    customer_class
0   0
1   NaN
2   0
```